# Upload a release artifact and its pom with Nexus Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I am trying to use Nexus Jenkins Plugin to upload a release artifact with its pom file.

The Nexus repository is configured with a deployment policy of "disable redeploy" so that releases can't be overriden.

To simplify the problem imagine I only want to upload my custom pom:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                nexusPublisher nexusInstanceId: 'nexusJose', nexusRepositoryId: 'nexusJose',
                    packages: [ 
                        [$class: 'MavenPackage', 
                        mavenAssetList: [ 
                            [classifier: '', 
                            extension: 'pom', 
                            filePath: "/libs/mylib-4.6.0.pom"],
                        ],
                        mavenCoordinate: [
                            artifactId: "mylib", 
                            groupId: "com.codependent.libs", 
                            packaging: "pom", version: "4.6.0"]
                        ]
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when nexusPublisher executes, Nexus is creating a default pom for those coordinates before performing the upload of the pom, so the upload of the actual pom fails as it already exists in the repository:

```
Uploading Maven asset with groupId: mylib artifactId: com.codependent.libs version: 4.6.0 To repository: thirdparty
Upload of /libs/mylib-4.6.0.pom failed
Failing build due to failure to upload file to Nexus Repository Manager Publisher
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
com.sonatype.nexus.api.exception.RepositoryManagerException: Unable to upload component: Bad Request <html><body><error>Repository with ID='thirdparty' does not allow updating artifacts.</error></body></html>
```

How can I upload an artifact with its own pom?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you don't need to configure uploading pom.xml file - Nexus Jenkins Plugin will upload your pom.xml file automatically. You just need to configure uploading of your release artifact.

So, in your case you can use the following configuration and your 'mylib-4.6.0.pom' should be uploaded automatically:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                nexusPublisher nexusInstanceId: 'nexusJose', nexusRepositoryId: 'nexusJose',
                    packages: [ 
                        [$class: 'MavenPackage', 
                        mavenAssetList: [ 
                            [classifier: '', 
                            extension: '', 
                            filePath: "${path-to-artifact}/mylib-4.6.0.jar"],
                        ],
                        mavenCoordinate: [
                            artifactId: "mylib", 
                            groupId: "com.codependent.libs", 
                            packaging: "jar", version: "4.6.0"]
                        ]
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This page can be useful:
https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/227256688-How-do-I-configure-the-Nexus-Jenkins-Plugin